# Smart CSS minifier?

Tags: css, minify

Is there a CSS minifier that's smart enough to do transforms like turning this:

```
.caret {
    border-left:4px solid transparent;
    border-right:4px solid transparent;
    border-top:4px solid #000;
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

into something like this:

```
.caret {
    border:4px solid transparent;
    border-top-color:#000;
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSSNano will do the trick.  I make it part of my Gulp process.  Does exactly what you've asked for and more.

http://cssnano.co/optimisations/